# Alternate audio driver (replace Realtek)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, audio, drivers, microphone

Is there any alternative to Realtek HD Audio driver? The reason I ask is because Realtek's audio driver makes my microphone sound really bad (friends tell me they can barely hear me). However, if I uninstall it my microphone works great and it transmits clearly.

The only problem with uninstalling the driver is, if I unplug my headphones (SteelSeries Siberia V2) and plug it back in, you can barely hear anything; even on max volume. I have to restart the computer with the headphones plugged in for the sound to go back to normal. I do not have this problem if I keep Realtek installed.

My laptop is ASUS S301LP with Windows 8.1 64 bit. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there's a generic third-party alternative.

Comment: Nothing? That sucks :(

Comment: If there were slight differences and 2 slightly different "driver" type things that people ever discuss with realtek chips it is the Driver that comes down with windows update OR the driver & software that you get from the manufacture implementing the chip (asus support) or possibly direct from realtek. Agrees with Karan that unlike gpus there has not been hacked up drivers, and if there were you could just replace one problem with another.  What kind of Driver/software package do you already have installed?

Comment: @Psycogeek After I uninstalled Realtek HD Audio driver, I think I have the generic Windows audio drivers. Pic: http://i.imgur.com/uUg6nvK.png

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. (not that i would know anyways)   If uninstalling the realtek software changes things, then you might have to get a little more advanced with the driver install, making sure that the driver you desire (or are testing) is the one that is in play at the time.  Then with the software&Driver packages realtek uses , you not only have the added "tabs" and info on the windows stuff, but also the realtek own software that could have some different controlling beyond what you see in the windows stuff.

Comment: Ok, I'll look more into it.

Comment: The drivers direct from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/) have more options than the ones Windows installs - might be worth trying both

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you, I tried installing the other options but the result was the same. It's ok though, I'll get used to the way it is now.